# How to get values from different tables from DB faster?

Tags: python, database, django-rest-framework, export-to-csv

so our DB was designed very badly. There is no foreign key used to link multiple tables
I need to fetch complete information and export it to csv. the challenge is the information need to be queried from multiple tables (say for e.g, usertable only stored sectionid in the table, in order to get section detail, I would have to query from section table and match it with sectionid acquired from usertable).

So i did this using serializer, because the fields are multiples.

So the problem with my current method is that its so slow because it needs to query for each object(queryset) to match with other tables using uuid/userid/anyid.

this is my views

```
class FileDownloaderSerializer(APIView):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

            filename = "All-users.csv"
            f = open(filename, 'w')                
            datas = Userstable.objects.using(dbname).all()                
            serializer = UserSerializer( datas, context={'sector': sector}, many=True)                                        
            df=serializer.data

        df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
        f.close()

        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename

        return response
```

so notice that i need one file exported which is .csv.

this is my serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Userstable
        fields = _all_
   section=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_section(self, obj):
        return section.objects.using(dbname.get(pk=obj.sectionid).sectionname

   department =serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   def get_department(self, obj):
        return section.objects.using(dbname).get(pk=obj.deptid).deptname
```

im showing only two tables here, but in my code i have total of 5 different tables

I tried to limit 100 rows and it is successful, i tried to fecth 300000 and it took me 3 hours to download csv. certainly not efficient. How can i solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't see anything wrong with the code you show.  There isn't much to go on here though to try to help you with your problem.  If the data you want is in multiple tables, then you need to be reading from multiple tables the way you describe.  There's really no way around that.  You want to do that efficiently, but I see nothing in your code that suggests you aren't doing that.  Any good ORM library should optimize your queries to make them as efficient as possible.  Can you provide more information about the layout of your database, and how you're querying it?

Comment: ...the thing you want to be on the lookout for is having to do the same lookup in the secondary tables multiple times. Properly written queries and/or a good ORM library should give you this pretty much for free.  If there's a reason that they can't, then you may need to look at pre-fetching the needed data in the secondary tables as a separate operation that you do once before peforming your main queries.  You would then perform a main query that didn't do the mapping to the other tables, and you'd then do that mapping in your own code to combine the results of each of your queries.

Comment: ...you also want to make sure that your queries are all backed by appropriate indexes in the cases where you're searching on something other than primary keys.  You seem to be only searching on primary keys, so maybe this isn't an issue for you.

Comment: on your second comment, I noticed that when I do 'print' something for each secondary tables. the code printed out every time for each lookup(each rows). If by my understanding, I would assume that the queries were run every and each time.

on other note, how would you prefetch the data for multiple usages?